# Can I sort on multiple fields in numpy structured array with some reversed, a la SQL ORDER BY

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, reverse

I have loaded the results from an SQL (MySQLdb) query into a numpy structured array. I now want to sort the array in various ways. The fields are a mixed bag of strings, ints, floats, and python objects (for the columns that came back with NULLS). I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972568/python-numpy-recarray-sort-bidirectional) but as askewchan mentions in the bottom of his answer, it doesn't work for strings, nor does it seem to work for python objects (e.g. ints but from a column with NULLS).

Is there a way to sort a one-dimensional structured array **in place** by one or more fields **of possibly non-numeric types** which may independently vary their direction (Ascending/Descending). Basically, I'm looking for something like SQL's 'ORDER BY' clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As he said in his answer:

> This works assuming all your values are numerical (since the negative won't reverse string sorting)

The thing you can do is convert your data to a pandas DataFrame. Since you already have your data in a NumPy arrays pandas wont do any copying of your data, it will reuse your data structures, so this operation is very cheap. After that you can do things like:

```
>>> a = np.array([(4, 'GE'), (1,'RE'), (1,'AE'), (4,'CD')],
                 dtype=[('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'S2')])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> df.sort(['x', 'y'], ascending=[0,1])
   x   y
3  4  CD
0  4  GE
2  1  AE
1  1  RE
>>> df.sort(['x', 'y'], ascending=[0,0])
   x   y
0  4  GE
3  4  CD
1  1  RE
2  1  AE
>>> df.sort(['y', 'x'], ascending=[1,0])
   x   y
2  1  AE
3  4  CD
0  4  GE
1  1  RE
>>> df.sort(['y', 'x'], ascending=[0,0])
   x   y
1  1  RE
0  4  GE
3  4  CD
2  1  AE
```

Comment: Yup, I saw it didn't work for strings, which is why I'm asking if there's another way to do it. That said, PANDAS seems to be that way. Thanks